# indexedDB object not found. location:"<unknown>"

Tags: indexeddb, firefox-os

In my desktop Firefox (32 and 33) I can access a datastore but from WebIDE with either OS 1.3 Simulator or my ZTE Open C device I get the object not found error. When using the simulator or device should I see the object using the indexedDB Browser? I have 2 apps, one creates and loads the data, the second accesses the data. In the browser they both work, in the simulator or device the create and load app works but the 2nd app gets the error after successful open on a 'transaction = localDatabase.db.transaction("myDB", "readonly")' statement. I have a count function in the load app and it shows the expected number of objects. I can wait till ver 34 where the Storage Inspector is being included but thought I'd see if there are any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have *storage* item in permissions list in manifest.webapp?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/App_permissions

Comment: Hi, I tried adding the storage permission to the manifest but still get the error.

Comment: Can you show your example?
My example of working app manifest that uses IndexDB https://github.com/nazar-pc/CleverStyle-Music/blob/master/manifest.webapp

Comment: Thanks for the manifest example. I'm thinking my problem has to do with trying to access the indexedDB from a second app so I'm going to combine the two.